# What is the difference between RSASSA-PSS signing and RSA-PSS signing?

Tags: rsa, signature, rsa-pss

I read the RFC 8017 and understood the pkcsv1.5 and pss padding techniques. I understood that in RSASSA-PSS signing scheme the signature will be appended at the end of M.

In some websites I read both RSASSA-PSS and RSA-PSS both are same, is it true? If not what is the fundamental difference between RSASSA-PSS and RSA-PSS, can you also please provide me the API's to sign and verify using  OpenSSL for RSASSA-PSS.

Thank You.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some authors draw a distinction between:

- **RSA-PSS**, analyzed by Bellare and Rogaway in 1996[[1]](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/exact) and proposed for IEEE P1363 in 1998[[2]](https://web.archive.org/web/20040713140300/http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/P1363a/contributions/pss-submission.pdf), which is roughly defined in terms of $H(r \mathbin\| m)$, and
- **RSASSA-PSS**, standardized in [IEEE P1363-2000](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/891000/) and [RSA PKCS #1 v2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162728/ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf), which is roughly defined in terms of $H(r \mathbin\| H(m))$.

This distinction is significant: RSA-PSS relies only on *target* collision resistance[[3]](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/tcr-hash-abstract.html) (or *universal one-way hash function…ness*[[4]](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=73011)) of $H$, while RSASSA-PSS relies on full collision resistance of $H$.

Another way to view it is that RSASSA-PSS—like RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and any other signature scheme where the message figures in only via $H(m)$—is *vulnerable* to collisions in $H$.  This spells bad news when $H$ is MD5, as many people used in practice for many years.  Academic cryptographers publicly demonstrated certificate forgery using an MD5 collision attack on RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5[[5]](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/)[[6]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.2.1); the United States and Israel forged a Microsoft software update signing certificate using an independently developed MD5 collision attack[[7]](https://www.cwi.nl/news/2012/cwi-cryptanalist-discovers-new-cryptographic-attack-variant-in-flame-spy-malware) to sabotage Iran's nuclear program.  But as far as anyone can tell, MD5's *target* collision resistance still holds up to this day, so **RSA-PSS would have thwarted this entire avenue for certificate forgery even with MD5.**

Why IEEE P1363-2000 and RSA PKCS #1 v2.1 standardized $H(r \mathbin\| H(m))$ instead of $H(r \mathbin\| m)$ is a mystery to me.  Coincidentally, this standardization happened around the same time that RSA, Inc., accepted a 10e6 USD bribe from the NSA to deploy Dual_EC_DRBG to all their RSA-BSAFE customers[[8]](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-security-rsa/exclusive-secret-contract-tied-nsa-and-security-industry-pioneer-idUSBRE9BJ1C220131221).

Modern signature schemes like Ed25519 use the design principle $H(r \mathbin\| m)$ in order to rely only on the weaker property target collision resistance like PSS or at least enhanced target collision resistance[[9]](http://webee.technion.ac.il/%7Ehugo/rhash/rhash.pdf), and as such are advertised to have collision *resilience*.  (More on the history of these and related concepts in a [previous answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67822).)

Comment: The actual hashclash attack was on a CA using MD5 + "v1.5" (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5), although I concur it _would have_ worked on MD5 + the PKCS1 version of PSS -- if any public CA was using that in 2009, which I very much doubt.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I had intentionally left it a little vague because I couldn't recall whether it was RSASSA-PSS or RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5.  I have updated the text to (a) point out the design mistake common to RSASSA-PSS and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, (b) confirm that hashclash attacked RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, and (c) continue to leave it vague what Flame attacked because in five minutes of searching I can't find a reference to support anything more specific than an MD5 collision attack in the Microsoft Terminal Software Licensing Service.  Better?

Comment: Almost always, if RSA-PSS is mentioned, it is just an abbreviation of "RSASSA-PSS" (as mentioned in [the answer by Gilles](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68540/1172)); the first time that I've seen it mentioned in combination with the original paper is here. As we're looking for differences it is logical to *assume* the original paper; I'm just mentioning because it is not common terminology.

Comment: The more likely reason to use $H(m)$ instead of $m$ as input is that most hardware don't like to get a possibly large message as input and prehashing it is a great way to accomplish this. Note that NIST doesn't particularly advertise MD5 as being secure and actually standardized a secure SHA-256 algorithm. That algorithm needs to be broken for collision resistance for any attack to work. Choosing $H(m)$ seems more like a practical choice to me than some kind of conspiracy.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one standard cryptographic mechanism that uses both the [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Operation) [trapdoor function family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function) and the [PSS](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.26.8704) [padding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)), and that's RSASSA-PSS defined by PKCS#1 v2.1 and above ([RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) being the current version of this standard). So “RSASSA-PSS” is the formal name of a cryptographic mechanism, and “RSA-PSS” is an unambiguous abbreviation of “RSASSA-PSS”.

---

> I understood that in RSASSA-PSS signing scheme the signature will be appended at the end of M.

This is not necessarily the case. [RSASSA-PSS signature generation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.1.1) takes an RSA key and a message as inputs, and produces a signature as output (unless it fails, in which case it produces a failure indicator but no output). You can append the signature to the message if you want, but you don't have to. In fact, you shouldn't *just* append the signature to the message: if you want to store or transmit the message and the signature together, always encode them in an unambiguous way. There are multiple ways to do that, for example with a header that indicates the length of the message and the length of the signature, and then concatenating this header, the message and the signature. But if you want to use a different encoding, that's fine.

Comment: As a comment on the "Signature Scheme with Appendix" part: the "with Appendix" is more mentioned to set it apart from "Signature Scheme with Message Recovery". It has little to nothing to do with the placement of the signature, other than to indicate that you'd need both the message and the signature to verify the data (as input parameters next to the public key, the used algorithm & configuration parameters, of course), whereas the message may be entirely contained in the signature if message recovery is used.