# Signature verification vs decryption?

Tags: encryption, signature

I've found this explanation regarding signature verification but I still confused

In the example in the picture, the sender **sign the hash using his secret key**. The output of signing produces a signature.

The receiver takes as input the signature and with the public key (**sent with the message**) verify it using verification algorithm and **produce the hash as output**. According to what I understand, the receiver performs the revere action, which is equivalent to encryption /decryption, using private/public key instead of the same private key.

Any clarification, please?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This diagram is not accurate.  Hashing is not a separate step outside signing for the convenience of handling long messages; hashing is an *integral part* of signing that is necessary for security.  And the verification algorithm does not always return a hash that you can compute separately: it only returns a boolean that indicates a valid signature or not.  In particular, **signature *is not* ‘encryption with the private key’**, which is a contradiction in terms, and very few signature schemes even resemble that idea.  Here is an accurate diagram:

[image: Diagram of a signature scheme: signature algorithm run by signer takes private key and data and returns signature; verification algorithm run by verifier takes public key, signature, and data, and returns boolean for valid or invalid.]

Note that hashing doesn't figure into this diagram, because it sits *inside* the signature algorithm and the verification algorithm; the *user*, who calls the signature algorithm or calls the verification algorithm, is not concerned with the hash function.

How does it work inside?  Let's examine an example of an RSA-based randomized signature scheme, RSA-PSS, which is related to (but [better than](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68581)) the standard RSASSA-PSS algorithm of [IEEE P1363-2000](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/891000/) and [PKCS#1 v2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162728/ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf):

[image: RSA-PSS embedded in signature and verification diagram: s^3 \equiv 2^t r + H(r \mathbin\| m) \pmod n]

There is a hashing step *inside*, but it is *randomized* with randomization that is embedded in the signature, so it's not just that we compute $\operatorname{MD5}(m)$—which would make us vulnerable to collisions in MD5!  If we skipped the hashing step, using $s^3 \equiv m \pmod n$ as the verification equation, the signature scheme would be totally insecure, *e.g.* I could forge 3 as a signature on the message 9—this is why hashing is not a separate step for the convenience of long messages, but actually crucial for something to be a secure signature algorithm at all.

In other signature schemes like Ed25519, there is no hash concealed within the signature that the verifier compares against a recomputed hash: a valid signature under a public key $A$ is a pair $(R, s)$ of a point $R$ and a scalar $s$ such that $[s]B = R + [H(R, A, m)]A$; here we are working in an elliptic curve, namely edwards25519, with standard base point $B$.  The hash $H(R, A, m)$ uses inputs that are embedded in the signature, so like RSA-PSS the hash can't be computed separately without the signature; and then the hash figures into some fancy math that returns a boolean answer $[s]B \stackrel?= R + [H(R, A, m)]A$ directly.

[image: Ed25519 embedded in signature and verification diagram: [s]B = R + [H(R, A, m)]A]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I did not quite get how the random `r` value appeared on the verifier side in the first graph. Does it also get passed via the signature itself?