# Exploiting weak hash functions in RSA-PSS

Tags: hash, signature, hash-signature, rsa-pss

I'm just trying to understand how a Weak/broken hash can break RSA-PSS or any other signature/encryption that uses it.
I know you can forge another message that has the same hash but that message probably doesn't mean anything, sending random numbers isn't really worth the trouble.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. If you are interested in Weak/broken hash function that can cause a break in RSA-PSS then it is a fine question, if you asking for any other signature/encryption then it is a broad question. This seems like a survey task, is it?

Comment: Also, which version  [What is the difference between RSASSA-PSS signing and RSA-PSS signing?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68531/18298)

Comment: "I know you can forge another message that has the same hash but that message probably doesn't mean anything"; actually, if the hash is vulnerable to a chosen prefix collision attack (which would include MD5 and SHA1), then the prefix of both messages can be perfectly legitimate; there will be some segment of data which is likely random looking (the part that the attack selects); however depending on the format the data is in, that might be unremarkable.

Comment: I'm interested in RSA-PSS and why a hash function works and why it's necessary for it to be collision resistant. how can a hacker for example exploit such weakness? like hashing with an MD5 or any other weak one like a hash function where H(2M)=4H(M)